# Why don't most major game engines use gifs for animated textures?

Tags: animation, graphics-programming, spritesheet

What is better to use Animation Sheets or Gifs? One advantage Gifs have over Animation Sheets is that you don't have to think about frames going too fast or too slow because of your code and updating in proper ticks.

What are the disadvantages to using Gifs and advantages Animation Sheets have over Gifs?

Comment: I kinda want to know if I am right with my thinking or not really. I just want pros and cons of using gif or animation sheet

Comment: Then perhaps you should reword your question to something like "Why don't most major game engines use gifs for animated textures?" as they aren't commonly, at least that I know of, for good reasons. I think that'd give you technical points on why they aren't used versus a which is better question, which are not appropriate for SE sites.

Comment: What are the advantages to using gifs?

Comment: `One advantage Gifs have over Animation Sheets is that you don't have to think about frames going too fast or too slow` Why that? On what are you relying to make that assumption? A library? The file format specification? A gif file is still just data, you still need code to interpret it (render it at the correct speed)

Comment: What hoffmale said. GIFs aren't magic; their animation still needs to be controlled and executed by some software, including its timing, and in this case, that software is written by you. Honestly I wouldn't expect your Animation Sheet handling code to differ a huge amount from your GIF handling code.

Comment: The only difference between your spritesheet and GIF code, is that your GIF code will convert the GIF into a spritesheet and then call the spritesheet code ;)

Comment: gif doesn't have any advantages. if you want inter-frame compression, then gif is approximately 30 times less efficient than a proper video codec, while also giving worse quality (for photorealistic stuff).

Comment: the history knows the usage of videos for textures though, for example Id Tech 3 used RoQ video codec for some animated textures.

Comment: It should be noted that early graphics software opened gif files as static image, not animated. This is because, as others have said, gifs aren't magically animated. The display software needs to animate it. Some later software animated gifs at the wrong speed because they assumed gif only had one frame rate. Even today, in 2016 we still have software like Adobe Photoshop that don't open gif in animated mode. Animation is the responsibility of the software, not gif. Thus in this case gif has no more advantage than any other file formats

Answer (score 90):

GIF drawbacks:

- very limited color palette, typically 256 colors with ugly dithering ([yes, you can have more than 256 colors in animated GIF](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/304/can-i-have-an-animated-gif-with-more-than-256-colours-per-frame), but this is uncommon)
- GPUs don't support GIF compression in hardware (means you will have to unpack them on CPU anyway)
- you only get to pick ONE color for transparency (unless implementing custom processing)
- no random access. All preceding GIF frames need to be read and decompressed to access a frame.
- being compressed. You need dedicated decompression function in code. You can't choose different (better) compression algorithms. (yes, [uncompressed GIFs exist too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Uncompressed_GIF), but this is uncommon)

With custom format all these items get resolved very quickly. You have much more control over image format, quality, transparency, random access and compression (including GPU-supported formats alike DXT). Even better, you can prioritize features you need.

> One advantage Gifs have over Animation Sheets is that you don't have to think about frames going too fast or too slow because of your code and updating in proper ticks.

Above statement is misleading. Syncing GIF fps with actual game fps is not much different than syncing custom sprites animation. In both cases you have exactly the same setup - a list of frames, desired framerate and render events. There is no magic powder in GIF - you will have to decompress GIF into spritesheet anyway, which defeats the purpose.

Of course some game engines may hide some of GIF issues behind the curtains, but then, same can be done with spritesheets in a better way.

Said that, there are some few cases where GIFs could *kind of work*. E.g. HTML/CSS GUIs, but these are quite rare and resource-hungry by themselves.

Comment: I don't understand "one color for transparency." What does it mean to have multiple colors for transparency? Are you talking about varying alpha values like applying a transparency gradient across a texture?

Comment: @Erik exactly that. Common GIF supports up to 256 colors, out of which just 1 can be marked to be transparent. Unlike other formats, where transparency typically has much wider range.

Comment: @Kromster Actually, resource savvy sites use custom animation mechanism for animated images, such as CSS `background-image` position animation where the animation is palced on one big image, which is then moved by offsets.

Comment: @TomášZato True. Sorry, did I state otherwise?

Comment: Of course they don't compress well, they are already compressed. Why would it be a drawback?

Comment: @luk32 this is a drawback because there are much better compression methods than old GIF compression. So you either use suboptimal GIF compression or get to (de)compress twice (note that compressing already compressed data generally yields larger size too).

Comment: My point is that the fact they are do not compress much is not a drawback itself, any texture storage using compression would exhibit this. It's obvious, one should not compress it. A drawback might be not being able to choose the method (or lack of one), which does limit usability a bit. BTW what are the much better compression methods? I've seen reports of 5-25% in PNGs deflate, vs GIFs LZW, it is not *that* much IMO, but sure it might be a serious limitation being stuck to LZW.

Comment: @luk32 the fact that they enforce specific compression is enough to be listed as a drawback. I'll update the answer, thanks for pointing!

Comment: @luk32 He didn't said that "gifs don't let themselves be compressed well" , he said that "gif compression is poor". And you don't use loseless compression in textures, you use lossy one like JPG, and then you measure difference not in percents but in times.

Comment: @Agent_L The bullet clearly said "*don't compress well*". Which itself doesn't have any merit. Sorry, if I wasn't clear enough. I meant there are other problem with GIF compression, but this wasn't one. JPG wouldn't compress well either, nor PVRTC or any other HW oriented texture compression algorithm. Just because they are already compressed formats. Kromster understood me, so I guess it's fine.

Comment: I don't think that generally has to be true (or I don't understand it fully), because you can create animated Gifs, where each Frame is a full frame, and not just the Diff-Image (don't know the official term for those Frames that only have the information that differs from the Frame before).
Although ofc, the GIF ist much bigger then.
But doesn't that mean you can have Random Access if the GIF is created this way?

Comment: @gsus Looks like, as with other drawbacks, this one can be worked around with using some uncommon GIF features. Could you provide a source please? I will be happy to add this into the answer.

Answer (score 32):

In order to use any image file as a texture in a game, there must be a texture created on the GPU and the pixel data in the image file must be loaded to that texture.

GPUs **do not** support many of the features that image files on CPUs support.  They don't support JPG compression, they don't support PNG compression, and with particular reference to GIFs, **they don't support auto-animation**.

So even if you did use a GIF file, you would still have to write your own animation and timing code anyway.  GIF gives you nothing.

Comment: Note that "CPUs" don't support those things, web browsers and operating systems do.

Comment: What, nobody's written a GPGPU web browser yet?

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune You laugh. I cry.

Answer (score 13):

GIF has a limited color palette. (255)
You have to implement parsing and animating the GIF too. So there is not a advancement in time nor in format's technical aspects.

Comment: 256 if you don't need transparency, 255 effective otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It's still 256 with transparency - just one of the colors is designated "transparent." I believe that information is stored in the header.

Comment: @DavidLively Hence "effective". The color is still there, but it can't be used as a opaque color.

Comment: @Kromster yeah. Deleted. I can has good maths.